# Geeting error in reading a file and pronting it as Label in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, label

I am trying to read text from a file and show it as Label in another screen but i am getting error that text file's content in not str even after using str() function.
Error:
ValueError: Screen1.usename accept only str

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Screen1(Screen):
    def gb(self):
        f=open('test.txt','r')
        b=f.read()
        t=str(b)
        return t
    usename = StringProperty("")

class Screen2(Screen):
    username = StringProperty("")


root = Builder.load_string('''

<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text:'ue'
            on_release: root.usename = root.gb; root.manager.current = "screen2"


<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    Label:
        text: root.username


ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
        id: loginscreen
    Screen2:
        username: loginscreen.usename

''')



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root
r=MyApp()
r.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
on_release: root.usename = root.gb
```

is trying to set the `usename` to a method (`root.gb`). You probably want to set `usename` to the return value of that method. Try just adding `()`, like this:

```
on_release: root.usename = root.gb()
```

Comment: Thank you very for the help. So now have both the methods working. Guys can choose one from these both 

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue, this's how we can read a text file and display it as label in another screen in kivy.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Screen1(Screen):
    f=open('test.txt','r')
    t=f.readlines()
    b=t[0]
    f.close()

class Screen2(Screen):
    username = StringProperty("")


root = Builder.load_string('''

<Screen1>:
    name:'xy'
    id:loginscreen
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text:'Execution button'
            on_release: root.manager.current = "screen2"


<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: root.username
        Button:
            text:'Back to menu'
            size_hint:.3,.3
            on_release: root.manager.current = "xy"

ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
        id:loginscreen
    Screen2:
        username: loginscreen.b

''')



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root
r=MyApp()
r.run()
```